# Issue with Shadow Copy and Shell Launcher in Windows - FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my .NET application in a Windows environment, specifically when utilizing Shell Launcher and attempting to enable shadow copy for the application.

**Code**

```
[LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost)]
[STAThread]
public static int Main() 
{
     if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain())
     {
        string assemblyPath = 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string assemblyFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(assemblyPath);
    AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
    setup.ApplicationName = assemblyFile;
    setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(setup.ApplicationName, null, setup);
    domain.ExecuteAssembly(setup.ApplicationName);
    AppDomain.Unload(domain);
    return 0;
}
  else
  {
    var application = new App();
    application.InitializeComponent();
    return application.Run();
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

When the application is configured as the shell launcher for a particular user, I'm facing a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` during the launch process. Strangely, this issue is isolated to the user with the Shell Launcher configuration; the application works flawlessly for other users. also when I am not using shadow copy it works well as the shell launcher

**Error Details:**

The error stack trace is as follows:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(System.String)
   at MyApp.App.Main()
```

**Steps Taken:**

1. Enabled Fusion Log to trace assembly binding. Logs indicate multiple failed attempts to locate the assembly.
2. Confirmed that the application works correctly for users other than the one configured with Shell Launcher.

**Question:**

I'm seeking assistance in identifying the root cause of this issue and possible solutions. Are there specific considerations or configurations needed when enabling shadow copy for an application set as the shell launcher for a Windows user? Any insights or guidance on resolving this discrepancy between users would be greatly appreciated.

**Environment:**

- Operating System: Windows
- .NET Framework Version: 4.8
- Application Type: WPF

Thank you in advance for your assistance!